# What is the upper found or Big O notation for the given functions

Tags: big-o

I'm trying to learn the upper bound(Big O) notation and I'm really confused with the below 2 types of functions.

1. f(n) = n^3 + 100n^2 + 5^n
2. f(n) = n^3 + 100n^2 + 1.1^n

Can someone please guide me how to find the big o notation of the given 2 functions.

Comment: This is probably better suited for [math.se] or [computerscience.se]

Comment: @Jose I do not think that the `complexity-theory` tag is appropriate. There is no analysis of an algorithm or similar involved.

Comment: @user17732522 ok, I will remove it

Answer (score 4):

`5^n` and `1.1^n` are exponential (growing) functions. They grow asymptotically faster than any polynomial function, which `n^3` and `n^2` are. (This can be proven e.g. via l'Hôpital.)

Therefore the functions are `Theta(5^n)` and `Theta(1.1^n)` respectively. Note that these classes are not the same, since an exponential function with a larger base/rate asymptotically dominates one with a smaller base/rate.

Comment: So what would be the exact order in Big O notation for these functions?

Comment: @Amrutha Big-O describes only upper bounds on the asymptotic growth, so e.g. both functions are `O(2^(2^n))` because they are definitively not growing that fast. `Theta` implies both an upper and lower bound. I know that the notation is unfortunately often misused, so if you like replace `Theta` by `O`.

Comment: Yes now I got it, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Big O notation is a mathematical notation that describes the limiting behavior of a function when the argument tends towards a particular value or infinity.

So as you can see, so the first function behave asymptotically like `5^n`, since the lower order terms when n tends to infinity are negligible. And the second one is dominated by `1.1^n` since is an exponential function and `1.1 > 1`.